# Scale without stretching or compressing

Tags: android, animation, view, stretching

Is it possible to animate a view with ScaleAnimation without compressing or stretching it ?

Or use AlphaAnimation from the bottom to the top to make it disappear ?

I want to make the view smaller without compressing the content of the view.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "compressing the content"?

Comment: If you use ScaleAnimation on a ListView for example from 1 to 0, items would be compressed (become smaller and smaller) and then disappear. I just want the layout to get smaller, not the content.

Comment: I tried a ListView in a LinearLayout but it doesn't work, it's still compressed during the animation

Comment: interesting, however from my understanding whatever animation you apply to the Layout will propagate to it's children. You might have to create a custom layout that will not do so.

Comment: I'm afraid i have to do so, thank you anyway

Comment: Did you solve this Raffy?